# Suggestion for best audio recording library for react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm currently dealing with recording stuff. I've never ever used any of these recording libraries before and having really a big hard time trying to find anything that works on mobile platforms. Please do suggest me any reliable library that is both actively maintained and have some examples i can lean on. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: please do some google before posting such question . for you question check below npm link https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-audio-record

Comment: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/04/audio-video-recording-react-native-expo/